# RequestParam as Set in single parameter

Tags: java, spring, parameters

I created endpoint with param as set:

```
@GetMapping("/me")
public MeDto getInfo(@RequestParam("param") Set<Integer> params) {
    ...
}
```

Everything works fine, but I need to send ids separetly e.g.

```
/me?param=1&param=2
```

Is there a way to make it as:

```
/me?param=1,2...N
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Pass a parameter of type String, and parse it in your controller. If you need to do that several times, use a specific class CommaSeparatedSetOfInteger as type, and define a data binder for that type: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder

Comment: which version of Spring are you currently using?

Comment: It should work out of the box, `WebConversionService` (more precisely, `StringToCollectionConverter`) is supposed to figure it out. 

Moreover, the second option is more preferable/readable/convenient, so I wouldn't even consider using the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/me")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getValues(@RequestParam String... param){
        Set<String> set= new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(param));
        return new ResponseEntity<Set>(set, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

So if you hit --> localhost:8786/me?param=hello,foo,bar,animals , you will get below response

[
    "animals",
    "bar",
    "foo",
    "hello"
]

Answer (score 3):

Okay I tested it in a new "Spring Environment" created on start.spring.io

It works out of the box, as already one in the comments said, but only with an Array of Integers (Not with a Set).
If you are gonna use one of the listed options you can remove duplicates of numbers (I guess this was your intention by using a Set) just with `Set<Integer> ints = Arrays.stream(params).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

When there definitely will be no "empty" number:

```
@GetMapping("/intarray")
    public Object someGetMapping(int[] params){
        return params;
    }
```

> http://localhost:8080/api/intarray?params=1,2,3,4,5,3

Output (As expected an array of integers):

```
[
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
3
```

]

And if there's probably an empty number in it, I would suggest to use Integer as an array.

```
@GetMapping("/intset")
public Object someOtherGetMapping(Integer[] params){
    return params;
}
```

> http://localhost:8080/api/intset?params=1,2,3,4,5,,,5

Output (with null values because there are empty fields in the query):

```
[
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
null,
null,
5
```

]